# Mongoose find value in array by index with specific condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to create a query that find a document in which each of the values of an array field must meet a different condition. 
Those condition differ by the index of this array.

i read that it can be done, for example, in this way:

```
var cursor = db.collection('inventory').find({ 
  "dim.1": { $gt: 22, $lt: 30 }
});
```

here i find document in which the array field "dim" has a value >22 & <30 in the second position.

I need to do the same thing with mongoose. but how?!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same query with Mongoose.

Assuming that your Mongoose model is **Inventory**, this should work:

```
Inventory.find({ 
  "dim.1": { $gt: 22, $lt: 30 }
}, function(err, docs) {
  // Callback code
})
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html